# Unification of applicators with different arity through substitution

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, substitution, unification, hindley-milner

I'm able to unify the following terms:

```
foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
bar :: (a' -> b') -> a' -> b'
foo bar

a ~ (a' -> b')
b ~ a'
c ~ b'

(a' -> b') -> a' -> b'
```

But I'm stuck applying the correct rules for the following unification, because `foo` expects a ternary function but `bar` has only two arguments:

```
foo :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> d
bar :: (a' -> b') -> a' -> b'
foo bar

-- ...?

(a' -> c -> d) -> a' -> c -> d
```

The inferred type comes from GHCI. How do I get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because `foo` expects a ternary function but `bar` has only two arguments

Well, always remember that Haskell doesn't really have binary or ternary functions at all – it just has unary ones. A ternary function is actually a unary function whose result is a unary function whose result is a function.

In this case, `bar'` must “fake” an extra argument by having `b'` be a function type. This is a special version of bar:

```
     -- b' ~ (d -> e)
bar :: (a' -> d -> e) -> a' -> d -> e
```

and voilà, `bar` has three arguments.

Now it should be clear how to unify this with the argument to `foo`.

Comment: Of course, abstraction over arity works not only for `foo` but also for the function argument `bar`, because it has the right return type (`b'`).